# For loop in R does not output correctly

Tags: r, loops, svm

My loop code did not output right. I'd like to loop through the `Test_Cs` and append to the  `test_accuracy` with the accuracy rate associated with each C value in `Test_Cs`. As there are 11 Cs being tested, I'd expect the `test_accuracy` to also have 11 values. However, my `test_accuracy` output has more than 1000 values, which signals something went wrong with my code.

```
#C is the sum of squared of all errors. The higher C means the more errors in the model and the model has low accuracy rate; C also >= 0. I will create a list of 11 C values I’d like to test the model with.

Test_Cs <- seq(0.01, 10000, length = 11)

#create a list of 0 to hold our predicted accuracies with different C values in the Test_Cs later on

test_accuracy <- rep(0, length(11))
x = 1

#loop multiple C through the KSVM model:

for (i in Test_Cs){
#call ksvm
   ksvm_model <- ksvm(as.matrix(data[,1:10]), as.factor(data[,11]), scaled=TRUE, type= “C-svc”, kernel =“vanilladot”, C=i)
#see what the model predicts
   pred <- predict(ksvm_model,data[,1:10])

# see what fraction of the model's predictions match the actual classification

   accu_percentage <- sum(pred == data[,11])/nrow(data)
   test_accuracy[[x]] <- accu_percentage
   x <- x+1
}

print(test_accuracy)
```

as the result of the command print(test_accuracy), I got more than 1000 output values, most of them are NA as below:

```
  [1] "C"                            "C:1000.009:0.862385321100917" "C:1000.009:0.862385321100917"
   [4] "C:0.01:0.863914373088685"     "C:1000.009:0.862385321100917" "C:2000.008:0.862385321100917"
   [7] "C:3000.007:0.862385321100917" "C:4000.006:0.862385321100917" "C:5000.005:0.862385321100917"
  [10] "C:6000.004:0.862385321100917" "C:7000.003:0.862385321100917" "C:8000.002:0.862385321100917"
  [13] "C:9000.001:0.862385321100917" "C:10000:0.862385321100917"    "0.862385321100917"           
  [16] "0.863914373088685"            "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"           
  [19] "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"           
  [22] "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"           
  [25] "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"            "0.863914373088685"           
  [28] "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"           
  [31] "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"           
  [34] "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"            "0.862385321100917"           
  [37] "0.862385321100917"            NA                             NA                            
  [40] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [43] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [46] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [49] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [52] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [55] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [58] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [61] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [64] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [67] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [70] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [73] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  [76] NA                             NA                             NA                            
  ....                       
 [988] NA                             NA                             NA                            
 [991] NA                             NA                             NA                            
 [994] NA                             NA                             NA                            
 [997] NA                             NA                             NA                            
[1000] "0.862385321100917"           
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 9000 entries ]
```

If you could help me diagnose the issue, it would be much appreciated. I think there are some logic flaws with the way I used `i` and `x` Thanks.

Comment: object which you created `test_accuracy` is not a list that you can assign something. try `test_accuracy <- list()` instead of `test_accuracy <- rep(0, length(11))`

Answer (score 0):

if you set 11 parameters to try in `Test_Cs`, your counter `x` would stop at 11. I created an empty list for `test_accuracy`

now it will work fine ;

```
Test_Cs <- seq(0.01, 10000, length = 11)

test_accuracy <- list()
x = 1

for (i in Test_Cs){
    
   ksvm_model <- ksvm(as.matrix(data[,1:10]), as.factor(data[,11]), scaled=TRUE, type= "C-svc", kernel ="vanilladot", C=i)
   pred <- predict(ksvm_model,data[,1:10])

   accu_percentage <- sum(pred == data[,11])/nrow(data)
   test_accuracy[[x]] <- accu_percentage
   x <- x+1
}

print(test_accuracy)
```